# How to import types in a jestEnvironment?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm setting a jest-environment for my tests, and apparently, these environments are not considered as `module` by Jest.
Therefore, I cannot use the ES6 syntax to `import` and `export`.

**That is why I am trying to find a way to import interfaces or types using `require`. Is it possible?**

This is my `jestEnvironment.ts`:

```
import Config = require('@jest/types');
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node').default;

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config: Config.ProjectConfig) {
    super(config);
    console.log(config);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.someGlobalVar = 'lala';
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  getVmContext() {
    return super.getVmContext();
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

And when running Jest, I get the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    /path/to/project/src/jestEnvironment.ts:1
    import { Config } from '@jest/types';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

(Just for information: I'm using ts-jest `26.5.6`... And I just saw that the version 28 introduced a support to ESM. However, there are too many breaking changes for me to switch to that version for now.)

Comment: Please add example code and error messages to your question. The short answer is that you'll need [ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest)

Comment: I'm already using `ts-jest`, but it really seems unrelated. This looks like a pure TypeScript/JavaScript problem.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support

Comment: I just checked it, and I get the same error, in addition to which I (weirdly) get: `Unknown option "extensionsToTreatAsEsm" with value [".ts"] was found.`

Comment: I don't know, but `import Config = require('@jest/types');` seems really wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm sorry, that was just while I was trying to import it using require. I tried that one, but I obviously tried `import { Config } from '@jest/types'` before that

Comment: I found out why I had the error before: I'm using `ts-jest` `26.5.6`, and your documentation shows that ESM support exists from version `27.1` ^^

Comment: I tried to "just update" `ts-jest` (without Jest) and it worked like a charm. Write your answer and I'll validate it!